# jQuery drag to select, constrained to elements, rather than typical drag box

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to use a drag to select feature, but rather than select a square area on screen, and select anything within that square, I want to select any element between my initial choice and the one I release the click on.

This is best explained visually. I **do not** want to do this:

[image: What I don't want to do]

Instead I want to do this:

[image: What I want to do]

Comment: Are you using a jQuery UI selectable widget as the basis for this feature, or did you roll your own?

Comment: At the moment I'm not using anything. The images are just mockups. I've been looking at jQuery UI and also http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the previous failed attempt I've now come up with a working solution. It would appear that jQuery UI selectable is not suitable, as it uses that rectangular selection, so I've had to roll my own.

In the example below (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSk9t/3/) for full code), the selectable elements are `a.date`. These elements should have `position: relative` set.

Firstly, I append a child element with class `.drag-proxy`. This is positioned absolutely, and covers the same area as the child. It's got no content so it sits transparently above.

These proxy elements are made draggable and droppable.

When the element is dragged and dropped onto another element, it is moved back to its starting point (so that subsequent selections work).

Then we cycle through all the proxy elements, indentifying the elements in the selection range, and then setting a class on the parent `a.date` element.

```
$(function() {
  $('a.date').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" class="drag-proxy" id="proxy_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"></a>');
  });

  var $currentlyDragged;

  $('.drag-proxy').draggable({
    start: function() {
      $currentlyDragged = $(this);
    },
    // Once drag has finished, return the drag-proxy to its original position
    stop: function() { 
      $(this).css('top', 0).css('left', 0);
      $currentlyDragged = null;
    }
  });

  $('.drag-proxy').droppable({
    over: function(e, ui) {
      var from_id = $currentlyDragged.attr('id');
      var to_id = $(this).attr('id');

      $('.date').removeClass('selected');

      var started = selecting = false;
      $('.drag-proxy').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var this_id = $this.attr('id');
        if (started === false && (this_id == from_id || this_id == to_id)) {
          selecting = true;
        }
        if (selecting) {
          $this.parent().addClass('selected');
          if (started === true && (this_id == from_id || this_id == to_id)) {
            selecting = false;
          }
        }
        if (started === false && (this_id == from_id || this_id == to_id)) {
          started = true;
        }
      });
    },

    drop: function(e, ui) {
      // do whatever you need to do once selection ends
    }
  });


});
​
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSk9t/3/) for the full example.

Answer (score 3):

If your boxes are within a list structure (ul or ol) you could detect the first and last boxes that the mouse has been dragged over and iterate through the collection using their identifiers as first and last indices to highlight as necessary.

Comment: Yeah, was hoping for a nice jQuery plugin that would do all that for me :)

Comment: @Colin, there is a attempt at a solution for jQuery UI selectables in [this forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-make-selectable-widget-work-with-continues-ranges). I did not test it, and the code can probably be improved, but maybe you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: @Frédéric - Thanks - that was a good starting point - I've managed to solve the problem, along with my unmentioned requirement of the selectables having to be in multiple containers. See http://jsfiddle.net/3JUvV/ - Do you want to form that as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @Colin, I could, but it would not be fair, as I only provided a link. On the other hand, *you* built on that information in order to learn something new and solve your problem (and not everyone does that). Therefore, IMHO [you should answer your own question then accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions). (Don't forget to include the source code from your fiddle as well as the thought process behind it).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks - have now done so, though I can't accept my own answer for 2 days apparently.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note - this answer is incorrect, but I'm leaving it as it shows the extent of what can be done with jQuery UI selectable, and why it doesn't work. See accepted answer for a custom-rolled, working solution.**

Thanks to Frédéric Hamidi for the pointer to [this forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-make-selectable-widget-work-with-continues-ranges), I have solved this as below. My additional requirements not mentioned in the question, were that the selectable elements have to be in multiple containers (ultimately this will be dates in a calendar, contained in individual months).

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="selectable">
  <div>
    <span id="a1">1</span>
    <span id="a2">2</span>
    <span id="a3">3</span>
    <span id="a4">4</span>
    <span id="a5">5</span>
    <span id="a6">6</span>
    <span id="a7">7</span>
    <span id="a8">8</span>
    <span id="a9">9</span>
    <span id="a10">10</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span id="b1">1</span>
    <span id="b2">2</span>
    <span id="b3">3</span>
    <span id="b4">4</span>
    <span id="b5">5</span>
    <span id="b6">6</span>
    <span id="b7">7</span>
    <span id="b8">8</span>
    <span id="b9">9</span>
    <span id="b10">10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then this javascript solves it. Note, the linked post uses `slice(start, end)` but I can't do that due to my multiple container requirement. So I've looped over all sortable elements with an `each()`, and toggled `selecting` based on if we've reached the first and not yet reached the last element.

I set `filter: 'span'` in order to prevent other child elements of `#selectable` becoming selectable.

```
$(function() {
  var rangeSelecting = function(event, ui) {
    var start = $(".ui-selecting", this).first();
    var end = $(".ui-selecting", this).last();
    var selecting = false;
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("range-selecting").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var this_id = $this.attr('id');
      if (start.attr('id') === this_id) selecting = true;
      if (selecting) $this.addClass('range-selecting');
      if (end.attr('id') === this_id) selecting = false;
    });
  }
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: 'span',
    selecting: rangeSelecting, 
    unselecting: rangeSelecting,
    stop: function(event, ui) { $(".range-selecting", this).addClass("ui-selected").removeClass("range-selecting"); }
  });
```

});​

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JUvV/) for a working example.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. It's doing strange things when end point is left of the start point on the second row. To be continued...

Comment: So the problem is that there's still an underlying rectangular selection, so the first one changes. Back to the drawing board.